# delete oldest records from database using ebean

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3, ebean

I am using Ebean with play framework(v2.3.4). This is my model:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  ...

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "parentID")
  public List<Notification> notifications = new ArrayList<Notification>();

  private static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, User.class);
}
```

I need to limit the number of `notifications` for every `user`. Is there a way to do it using Ebean automatically?

what I need is that  if the number of `notifications` records for a single `user` grows above lets say 50, then the oldest records are deleted (i.e. the new records above 50 'replace' the oldest records)

Comment: I doubt it is possible to limit with Ebean. What you can do is to always select 50 bottom rows. And optionally you can have a background cleaning task scheduled to periodically clean old notifications above 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible, Ebean is an ORM so it doesn't bring any logic with it (that's obvious why it should?).

Instead you need to use i.e. Akka Scheduler within your app, which will periodically perform cleaning for all users, alternatively you can also add such *cropping* at every/n-th saving operation i.e. by overriding `save()` method within your model.